# How can I build a successful empire ruled by a malevolent ruler?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources, empire-building, evil

Right now, I'm trying to build an empire (based on byzantine) that is set as the main enemy.

In an empire, does the ruler interact with their people? What is their empire's history?

The empire I'm building was a town, then a kingdom, and finally an empire.

But how can a town turn into a kingdom? What are the methods the kingdom use to become an empire other than taking over other nations? What does the ruler do to make their subject loyal to them even if they are bad, morally or otherwise? How people used to travel to other countries? What about the geographics of an empire?

Also, I have a problem dealing with the worldbuilding fundamentals such as geography, culture, history, politics, economy, etc.

Comment: This seems highly dependent upon what you as a worldbuilder want from your empire, how write the empire in your works, and the level of detail you choose to expose. Open ended questions, and questions that are highly dependent upon worldbuilder discretion are not appropriate for this site. My fundamentals for building an empire may be entirely different from yours but still equally valid.

Comment: @sphennings I agree but my problem is that I don't know what are the fundamentals for building an empire and how to do so in a believable way.

Comment: *"The empire is ahead of other kingdoms and empires in terms of economy"* and *"the empire's people live in misery"* are contradictory requirements... You cannot have an empire which is strong, powerful and victorius, while at the same time its people live in misery. (And the Roman Empire never called itself "Byzantine". The moniker "Byzantine" was invented by a German historian long after the fall of Constantinople, as a way to make it easier for readers to distinguish between the real but dead Roman Empire and the fake but at that time very much alive Holy Roman Empire of the German Nation.)

Comment: Aren't all worlds pre-apocalyptic?

Comment: @AlexP I am aware that "Byzantine" is a nickname for the eastern roman empire. (Though I like the sound of it.)
The empire is a part of a work-in-progress novel, so any elements are subject to change.
The idea behind people living in misery is because of how they are treated by their Empress.
What do you suggest?

Comment: @Daron Yeah, why?

Comment: *"People living in misery is because of how they are treated by their Empress":* (1) You seem to have a completely erroneous idea about how powerful an absolute monarch really was in pre-modern times. In reality, the vast majority of people never ever interacted with the state in any capacity. (2) If the monarch makes their people's lives miserable, then the entire state is miserable. Poor people don't really pay much tax, and without much tax the monarch cannot have much of an army. The basic rule is that to have a rich country you must have rich people living in it.

Comment: @AlexP Ah, I see. As I said in my post, I have no idea how to build an entire country, even if it is based on a real-life one, or if there are any websites/resources talking about empires and such.
Some time ago, I imagined that the Empress is charismatic and works for gaining others' trust (her people, her subjects, etc.)
Yeah, I'll need to revise some ideas since they are contradictory,

Comment: @m_ihsanart It's your world. You can choose to follow whatever fundamentals you want. There are no secret true fundamentals of worldbuilding. Just whatever limitations you choose to impose on yourself. I think you'll find that believability has less to do with any fact of your world and far more to do with how you choose to present those facts to your audience. If you write a compelling story the audience will overlook all sorts of worldbuilding sins. Since believability is a result of the quality of the writing, not the world itself, it's not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: @m_ihsanart Because the apocalypse hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Daron But it will happen, eventually :D

Comment: @m_ihsanart That's what makes it pre-apocalyptic.

Comment: What's your question here? How to build an empire (can be on-topic) or how to make a believable evil ruler (off-topic since it's about a lone individual)? Also, for max clarity rewrite the question in the body.

Comment: @Tortliena About building the empire.
So questions about character making are not supposed to be here? Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: @m_ihsanart Yes, characters are off-topic as even if they are part of the world, anything about them are too reliant on who they are individually. You can have a more complete description (and others's opinion) on what's on-topic and what isn't [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9815/80336) :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Model your Empress on a real Byzantine emperor.**

There were a lot of them.  They were conquerors.  They did things which to our modern sensibilities seem evil.  You have ample historical precedent to draw from.

Perhaps **Basil the Bulgar Slayer**?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Kleidion

> Skylitzes records that Basil completely routed the Bulgarian army and
> took 15,000 prisoners... Basil divided the prisoners into groups of
> 100 men, blinded 99 men in each group and left one man in each with
> one eye so that he could lead the others home...

That would be an attention getter when they all came home.  Sometimes I think about how things went with those blind soldiers afterwards.  Those hungry blind men, who could not help take in the crops.  Is that the act of an evil Emperor?  Where does practical leave off and evil start?

In any event you can borrow liberally from actual history and so your events will be realistic.  These events can couch your description of the inner life of your empress; her motivations, mental struggles etc.

I really enjoyed the Norwich books on Byzantium.  That is how I knew about the blinded army.  You could get them used for cheap.  [https://www.amazon.com/Byzantium-Centuries-John-Julius-Norwich/dp/0394537785](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0394537785)   There were empresses too.  Empress Irene gets full marks for calculated brutality.

Comment: +1 for Basil the Bulgar Slayer

Comment: Thanks for the resource!